# Return ticket from USA, is it necessary to be for country of origin?

Tags: transit, india, singapore, southeast-asia

I was travelling from Delhi to San Francisco and had return ticket from San Francisco to Singapore. I was not issued boarding pass on the grounds that I don't have tickets for Singapore to Delhi. 
Standing on the booking counter, I had to purchase and show this ticket to counter clerk before he issued me boarding pass.
Was the airlines right on insisting it?

Comment: The issue is not country of origin, but your rights to leave the airport in the apparent country of destination. Guessing that you are an Indian national, you should have been able to board _with an electronic visa for Singapore_.

Answer (score 4):

The US has no return ticket requirement except for travelers using the Visa Waiver Program.  Even for those travelers, the ticket [only needs to be valid to transport the traveler to a destination outside North America](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2#c_1).  It is possible that the airline refused entry based on Singapore's documentary requirements, but more likely that they were wrong to deny boarding.